# How can I define a function to accept only either an array of strings or an array of integers as an argument?

Tags: python, list, parameters

I would like to define a function with the parameter specified as "array of strings" or "array of integers", without looping through the individual array elements to check the type of each. Specifically, I would like the function to only allow passing of the two above-mentioned array types in order to run, in the same way one would be able to specify `function(param: str)` to only accept strings, for example.

I defined separate functions as `function(param: list[str])` or `function(param: list[int])`. But I could not figure out how to implement both simultaneously.

Comment: Do you want this to be checked by static type checkers, or at runtime?

Comment: At runtime you can't know what each value in a list is without looping through them. An array is just a pointer to its first element, it has no metadata AFAIK. You have to either sanitize arrays before passing them into function or check inside the function.

Comment: `list[str | int]`?  https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-604-new-type-union-operator

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think they would want `list[str] | list[int]`

Comment: Note, you're using "array" and "list" interchangeably. This may cause confusion.

Comment: What does your function *do* with the list? If, for example, you accept a list of strings in order to first convert each string to an integer, I would simply require a list of ints and let the caller be responsible for correctly turning a list of strings into a list of ints.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typing` to *hint* at what this should be, but to really assert the values, you'll need to check them all
conveniently, `all()` will short-circuit on the first non-Truthy value

Typing

```py
from typing import Union

def function(param: Union[list[str], list[int]):
    ...
```

To assert at runtime

```py
def function(param):
    try:
        param_iter = iter(param)
    except TypeError as ex:  # param is not iterable
        raise TypeError(f"param must be iterable, but got {type(param)})" from ex

    for test_type in (int, str):
        if all(isinstance(v, test_type) for v in param_iter):
            break  # escape for loop
        param_iter = iter(param)  # fresh iterable and continue
    else:  # did not break
        raise TypeError("function only accepts homogenous iterables of int or str")
    ...  # rest of function
```

NOTE this is a bit more permissive allowing `param` to be any *iterable*, but you can go ahead and assert whatever else you like - beware, however, that this design will consume generators, so more work would be wanted to collect and assert their values (realistically, warning callers with comments and usage hints tends to be better than trying to force them to use your function the way you intend it to be used)

Comment: Try to avoid looking at error messages. You can check if `param` is iterable by first trying to get an iterator: `i = iter(param)`. If it's not iterable, it will raise a `TypeError` similar to the one you are creating explicitly. If no error is raised, *then* you can proceed to check `all(isinstance(x, int) for x in i)`. If true, proceed. If false, get a fresh iterator with `i = iter(param)` again and check if they are all strings.

Comment: indeed / cheers! away from python shell for type hints too let me do some cleanup - maybe worth adding more about the generator case too, but practically, such a thing is highly implementation-specific, might work with a context manager, etc. but best to just tell the caller "don't do that" and be itself a generator

Answer (score -2):

I'm still a beginner, but I will try :)

IDK how to do it, but you can check the first element and compare it with the rest of list

```
def func(param: list):
  if type(param[0])!=int and type(param[0])!=str:
    raise Exception("this function accepts only array of integers or array of strings")
  for i in range(1,len(param)):
    if type(param[i]) != type(param[0]):
      raise Exception("this function accepts only array of integers or array of strings")
```

Comment: To be more concise you could write something like `all(type(item) == int for item in param)`.

Comment: I like the idea of checking that the *first* element is of the right type, then verifying that the rest of the elements match the first type. Don't compare types with `==`, though. Do something like `t = type(param[0])`, then make checks like `issubclass(t, (int, str))` and `for x in param[1:]: if isinstance(x, t): ...`.

Comment: If you are willing to trust that your code will pass static type checking before execution, you can simply use `def func(param: list[str] | list[int]):` and dispense with the runtime checks.